# Can I use RANS to see the effect of mixed convection?

Tags: pde, fluid-dynamics, comsol

my question is: can I use a RANS simulation to see the effect of mixed/natural convection?

Actually I have also a second question: I would like to do this in Comsol multiphysics, but it seems that it has no model that takes into account turbulence (like k epsilon, Reinolds stress, LES, ecc..). 
Ps: this could be because I use a pretty old version of the software, but anyway I haven't found documentation about this topic so far.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: What are your Rayleigh and Reynolds numbers?

Comment: I haven't set the case yet, but would be such as $\frac{Gr}{Re^2} $ would be near 1, to guarantee mixed convection.

Comment: I think that you've got to know whether the flow is likely to be turbulent before you can know if RANS is applicable.